# signtool error in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

After rebuilding my c++ project, I got this error message at my output box inside Visual Studio 2008.

```
1>SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Signing library..."
```

How to solve this?

update:
here is from my visual studio setting...

```
signtool sign /n "Against Intuition Oy" /t  http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts   /timstamp.dll Release\WOT.dll
```

Comment: you're running a postbuild event in which something gets signed using SignTool, but no certificate was found. You should post the postbuild command line, and eventually the command used to create the certificates

Comment: thx for replying. how to get the postbuild command? i do not know about this before? usually i compile in debug mode its ok. but when try to compile in release mode, this error appear :(

Comment: i update my Question..just found the Post Build window.

Answer (score 2):

signtool cannot find a cerificate named "Against Intuition Oy" in your certificate store; do you have it?

Try running signtool from the command line, try some different options to see if it works out. Run 'signtool sign /?' to get information, or check msdn for additional info.

You can create certificates yourself:

```
makecert -r -pe -ss MyTempCert -n "CN=Against Intuition Oy" MyTempCert.cer
```

sign:

```
signtool sign /a /s MyTempCert /n "Against Intuition Oy" Release/WOT.dll
```

If you do not need signing, disable or delete the postbuild event in the project's setting (in release mode, your debug mode doesn't have it) and obviously you will not get errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same error only because my user account had no password.

Setting a password for the user account fixed the issue.